# flask запуск задач по расписанию

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, redis, celery

В связи с нехваткой знаний, прошу помочь определится в выборе.
В базе данных sqlalchemy, есть группа пользователе которым нужно пару раз в день отправлять письмо с вложением. Многие советуют использовать для этих задач Celery или Redis. Или нет смысла в установке лишних сервисов, и все делать через cron?
В чем плюсы рассылки через celery, нужен ли для этих целей Redis!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете легко настроить задачу Celery так, что в случае сбоя отправки письма, задача будет повторяться нужное количество раз с увеличением временного интервала между попытками. Cron вам такого удобства не предоставит, придётся либо смириться с негарантированной доставкой, либо велосипедить собственный алгоритм обработки сбоев. Но нужен ли вам этот функционал действительно и готовы ли вы ради него городить инфраструктуру очереди задач? Это только вам решать.

Да, для работы Celery нужен брокер очередей - Redis или RabbitMQ.

Comment: Спасибо! Исчерпывающий ответ.

Comment: @Vadim [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Celery и Redis - это дополнительные сущности, которые нужно настраивать и поддерживать. Для Celery нужен дополнительно брокер сообщений, и база данных для хранения результатов. Если задание всего одно, запускается два раза в день, и количество пользователей не велико (например до сотни) то все таки посмотрите в сторону cron, или если используется uwsgi, то [uwsgi.timer](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PythonDecorators.html#uwsgidecorators.timer).

Celery не поможет вам определить, когда письмо отправилось, а когда нет. Это все равно придется делать в ручную, либо искать готовые модули.

Как вариант можно рассмотреть связку с postfix, который будет запущен локально. В [postfix](http://www.postfix.org) есть очередь отправки, правда на счет гибкости ее настройки я не в курсе.